# Codeigniter Group By Date On Table

Tags: codeigniter

I have data from one table, let's say t_schedule, by default, they are shown like this

|Date           |Time       |Activity   |
|2014-12-22|08.00.00|Activity 1|
|2014-12-22|09.00.00|Activity 2|
|2014-12-22|10.00.00|Activity 3|
|2014-12-23|08.00.00|Activity 1|
|2014-12-23|09.00.00|Activity 2|
|2014-12-24|08.00.00|Activity 1|
|2014-12-24|09.00.00|Activity 2|
|2014-12-24|10.00.00|Activity 3|

I want to show them like this

|Date           |Time       |Activity   |
|2014-12-22|08.00.00|Activity 1|
|                   |09.00.00|Activity 2|
|                   |10.00.00|Activity 3|
|2014-12-23|08.00.00|Activity 1|
|                   |09.00.00|Activity 2|
|2014-12-24|08.00.00|Activity 1|
|                   |09.00.00|Activity 2|
|                   |10.00.00|Activity 3|

How should I do? Can somebody halp me, please?

Comment: You should show us what you have in your code. And format the data/code snippet you paste here.

Comment: try `$this->db->group_by('year(your_date), month(your_date), day(your_date)');` or `$this->db->group_by('date(your_date)');`

Comment: SELECT * FROM agenda a JOIN detail_agenda d ON a.id_agenda=d.id_agenda ORDER BY a.id_agenda DESC, I dont want to show date column if it has the same value with data before.

Comment: You cannot do it with query. You need to convert new array from the result.what is your model and view look like?

Comment: I tried it, but the result only show two records, like when I used DISTINCT statement, how to show the other data below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want do this by `query` then you have do a complex `query`, rather than you can do it in `view`. I think you have use a loop to show the the first result. if just modify it just little bit than it will be shown like you desired output.

```
<?php $last_date = ''; ?>
<?php for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++): ?>
     <tr>
         <?php if($result[$i]->date != $last_date): ?>
               <td><?php echo $result[$i]->date; ?></td>
               <?php $last_date = $result[$i]->date; ?>
         <?php else: ?>
               <td></td>
         <?php endif;?>
         <td><?php echo $result[$i]->time; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $result[$i]->activity; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

I have just giving you an example, i hope you can solve your problem now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for your interest in helping me, your solution works! :)